# How to store Records (json) on webpage and show only on record on View

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 10 records in json array that comes from api call. But I need to show only 1 record on webpage providing next and previous buttons. So when user clicks on next or previous buttons I need to fetch the next or previous records and display on webpage. Something like viewpager in android or flipview in windows apps.

The reason why I want to store is just to avoid unnecessarily api calls to server fetching record and also pointers to next and previous record.

Is it possible to store those 10 records in some javascript variable and keep iterating when user clicks on next and previous.

Server side I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can be done. Just format your JSON correctly to hold an array of records, and maintain an index pointing to the current record.

To update the display you can either use pure JavaScript or utilize some kind of MVVM library (for example) like Knockout or Angular.